# Free maps api and geocoding

Tags: api, mapping, geocoding

I have to develop an *commercial* application with mapping.
I can't use Google Maps because of the 10k$/year for the premier API...

I tried Mapstraction with OpenStreetMap, nice but with some limitations. 
There is no geocoding available apparently.

Is there a good free(or affordable) service available anywhere with mapping & geocoding functionnalities ?

Thanks

Comment: MapQuest is offering a service based on OSM: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest

Comment: And of course OpenLayers for mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this question is still valid, I think you should check [Open Data Map APIs](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open), in Open Web Services section. **No limits, no signup tricks to get the API keys, everything free for real!**

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull in github for the feature : https://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/pull/98